# How to convert column type from str to date when the str is of format dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: sql, date, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv, databricks

I have a large table in sql I imported from a large csv file.

A column is recognized as a str when it contains date information of format dd/mm/yyyy.

I tried `select TO_DATE('12/31/2015') as date` but that does not work because TO_DATE function needs yyyy-mm-dd format.

How can I rearrange the '12/31/2015' string to '2015-12-31' format inside sql so that I can convert the column type to date?

I am doing this on a sparkSQL (on databricks environment ) due to the very large size of the data where the `update` keyword of sql does not seem to be supported.

Answer (score 2):

Just re-read your question;

I would suggest this:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = Convert(varchar(10), Convert(smalldatetime, column, 103), 120)
```

This converts the column value to smalldatetime, using the british format (dd/mm/yyyy), then converts it back to varchar, using the 120 format (yyyy-mm-dd); The 120 format contains time info, but this will be truncated because it's being cast back as varchar(10);

Test it:

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(10), Convert(smalldatetime, column, 103), 120)
FROM table
```

Comment: Thank you. This is not a fair question since I did not make it clear before that It seems that the update command is not supported in sparkSQL. (I could be wrong) Any advice in this scenario?

Comment: I just tried the test statement and got the following error:
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot recognize input near 'varchar' '(' '10' in function specification; line 1 pos 15

Comment: Hi Semihcan, I've tried the statement I wrote on my PC, and had no problem, so I'm guessing it's a platform compatibility issue; I've checked your tags & see you've used apache-spark-sql while I'm using straight SQL; my apologies I may not be able to help any further.

Answer (score 0):

The below link answer works
 **https://forums.databricks.com/answers/12121/view.html**

df.withColumn("tx_date", to_date(unix_timestamp($"date", "M/dd/yyyy").cast("timestamp")))